# 1-1 and onto functions between $A=\{z \in \mathbb{C} | |z| >1\}$ and $B=\{z \in \mathbb{C} | z\neq 0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

I am solving question of a institute in which I don't study and I was unable to solve this question.

> Let $A=\{z \in  \mathbb{C} \mid |z| >1\}$ and $B=\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid z\neq 0\}$. Then which of the follwoing holds:

**A** There exists a continuous onto function $f: A \to B$

**B** There exists a continuous 1-1 function $f: B \to A$

**C** There exists a non- constant analytic function $f: A \to B$

**D** There exists a non- constant analytic function $f: B \to A$

I have done C, D but no progress can be made on A , B . I have studied complex analysis from Bak , Newman in case its helpful. I am unable to use any concrete reasoning for A , B.

Please tell me how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify that $e^{z}$ is a continuous function from $A$ onto $B$ and $\frac {1+|z|} z$ is a continuous one-to-one function from $B$ into $A$.

Comment: @User I will be happy to give hints if you cannot verify these facts.